# If I add someone as an Editor to a Google Doc, can they see the old version history?

Tags: google-docs, permissions, version-control

I created a Google Doc, made some edits, then added a colleague as an Editor. Can they see in the "Version history" the edits I made prior to adding them? (Important because I was editing a draft and I don't want them to see my scratch work.)

Comment: Yes. If you need further help, please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask]